# MySql Query to find out first 50% of records from a Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am trying to fetch first 50% of records from a MySQL Table User. I know we can use limit or top for finding them but the total number of records are not fixed so hard coding the actual number in the limit or top doesn't gives me first 50% of records. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could always search - for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20260/select-top-in-mysql

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this: [`ntile()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile) does exactly what you ask for. Assuming that your ordering column is `id`:

```
select *
from (select t.*, ntile(2) over(order by id) nt from mytable) t
where nt = 1
```

In earlier versions, one option is a user variable and a join with an aggregate query:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    fom (select * from mytable order by id) t
    cross join (select @rn := 0) x
    cross join (select count(*) cnt from mytable) c
) t
where rn <= cnt / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql directly not supports this. You can try with two queries or use subqueries

Something like this.

1. find the count of total records/2
2. that value has to be applied in the limit clause.

   SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM table);

   SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ', @count);

Answer (score 0):

for example employee is your table having 6 rows

select *  from Employee
where empid <= (select count(empid)/2 from employee);

gives the 3 rows(means 50% of data from the employee table)..

Answer (score -1):

**select x.* from (select *, ntile(3) over(order by id) nt from your_table)xwhere nt = 3;strong text**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table name LIMIT (select COUNT(*)/2 from table name);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.